# Is there another way to add user input to SPARQL queries in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, sparql

For a school project last year, I made a web application where the user can choose from a number of categories to get a recommended movie. This was done by parametrizing user input into prewritten SPARQL queries. However, the user is currently only able to find a movie if they give an input for all categories. For personal use, I would like to change this so that the user can choose only for example "Comedy", and get all comedies regardless of for example the runtime or decade in which it was released.

The user can choose between four categories like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZKtg.png).

And the user input is being parametrized in the following way:

```
    if (chosenDecade == "Choose decade here" || chosenGenre == "Choose genre here" || chosenLength == "Choose runtime here" || chosenCountry == "Choose country here"){
        alert('Please provide all values!')
    } else {
        var mySparqlQuery = encodeURI('
PREFIX mo: <http://www.movieontology.org/2009/10/01/movieontology.owl#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX fp: <http://example.com/FinalProject/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?title ?plot ?genre ?releaseYear ?runtime ?countryLabel ?metascore ?imdbRating ?imdbID 
WHERE { ?movie rdf:type mo:Movie ; 
               rdf:type fp:' + chosenDecade + 'Movie ; 
               rdf:type fp:' + chosenLength + 'Movie ; 
               fp:hasGenre ?genre ; 
               mo:hasTitle ?title ; 
               fp:hasPlot ?plot ;
               mo:hasRuntime ?runtime ; 
               fp:hasReleaseYear ?releaseYear ; 
               mo:hasReleasingCountry ?country ; 
               fp:hasIMDbID ?imdbID ; 
               mo:hasIMDbRating ?imdbRating ; 
               fp:hasMetascore ?metascore .
               FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?genre), "' + chosenGenre + '")) 
               FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?country), "' + chosenCountry + '")) } ').replace(/#/g, '%23');
    }
```

What I want to know is if there is a way to enable the user to not have to provide all values (for example only one value) without having to write the logic for each specific case (I guess it would be 16 different cases), i.e. for example

```
if (chosenDecade != "Choose decade here" && chosenGenre == "Choose genre here" && chosenLength == "Choose runtime here" && chosenCountry && "Choose country here")
```

followed by the SPARQL query without the chosenGenre, chosenLength, chosenCountry variables (in the case where the user only provides the decade).

I am an amateur at this, so I apologize if the code is painful to read.

Comment: What *is* the logic for one case?

Comment: I mean, it's rather trivial. Just add only those triple patterns and filter clauses to the SPARQL query for the values that have been provided. Done. So you could simply create the query string by e.g. concatenating `rdf:type fp:' + chosenDecade + 'Movie ;` to the query string only if the decade value has been given